# Apple ID shows different names

Tags: apple-id

While trying to make a Genius Bar reservation, the name appearing in the reservation is different from the one appearing in my profile—I modified it at some point. Why is that and how can I update the one from the reservations page?

Also, when I’m trying to edit it from the reservations page, it redirect to the account page, where the name is correct.

Genius Bar reservations page:
[image]

My account page:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have detected that the database Apple is using for store reservations is different than the one you see on the My Apple ID page.

You can correct that information by asking them at the bar to assist in correcting and if they say to log in and change it, you can do that on one of the store machines (or your own if you don't trust Safari's private browsing function) and ask them to check that the changes are effective.

Sometimes, you need to call the main AppleCare support number if there is a problem with your record, but most cases you can fix at the time when you see the difference.

Comment: I just came back from a store and they couldn’t fix it, so it seems that I need to call AppleCare.